# how can I properly validate a REST API query parameters?

Tags: python, flask

I am creating an api mock for my real rest api where I want to validate some parameters that are optional, but however I am getting always `all items` where it should print each section based on the given parameter, in the case of the following mock request will return `None` if after `=` is empty , and it will raise error 400.

```
xxxxx?vendor=&product=
xxxxx?search=
xxxxx?sort=
```

group validation

- product_id > solo
- vendor + product , together
- search > solo
- _sort > solo
- _sort + items , together

I am gettting the following output

```
all items
product_id
all items
all items
all items
all items
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

```
def api_wrapper(product_id=None, vendor=None, product=None, search=None, _sort=None, items=None):
    if not product_id or vendor and product or search or _sort or _sort and items:
        print('all items')
    elif product_id:
        print('product_id')
    elif (vendor and product):
        print('vendor + product')
    elif search:
        print('search')
    elif _sort == 'lastest' or _sort and items:
        print('lastest or _sort + items')
    else:
        print('error 400 invalid')

api_wrapper()   # /api/v1/xxxxx
api_wrapper(1)  # /api/v1/xxxxx?product_id=<ID>
api_wrapper(None, 1,2)  # /api/v1/xxxxx?vendor=<vendor>&product=<product>
api_wrapper(None, None, None, 1)  # /api/v1/xxxxx?search=<search>
api_wrapper(None,None,None,None, 'lastest') # /api/v1/xxxxx?sort=latest
api_wrapper(None,None,None,None, 'lastest', 2) # /api/v1/xxxxx/?search=<search>&size=<items>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot parenthesing everything after the `not` in the first `if`. Like `if not (product_id ... items):`. `not` is one of the lowest-precedence operations, in its current form it applies to `product_id` only.

Comment: if I use if not (...) only applies to product_id , how can I properly validate it?

Comment: Ok, then you may wanted `if p_id and not (everything else):` that would check for the presence of productid and the lack of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Short Circuit logic evaluation, your logic condition is faulty.
`product_id` will be falsy in the event of a default invocation, which makes the expression `not product_id` truthy. since `or` short-circuits on truthy, the entire expression is evaluated as truthy and the "all items" case is reached.

```py
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> product_id = None
>>> vendor = None
>>> bool(not product_id)
True
>>> not product_id or vendor
True
```